# Error cannot POST when using REST api and Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, rest

I have problems with the REST API.

I have a file named Route. In which I make a request that is then passed to the server where it is called. In my third request, I want to select an ID to pass it as an API and write to call the page inside/:id, but I only get an error (This is a POST request)

*Error: Cannot POST /inside*

Route.js

```
const post_inside = (req, res) => {
    var config = {
        user:'postgres',
        database:'my',
        password: '1',
        host:'localhost',
        port:5432,
        max:10,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    }
    var pool = new pg.Pool(config)

    pool.connect(function(err, client, done){
        if(err){
            return console.error('error')
        }
client.query("SELECT *,to_char(data_roz::date , 'YYYY-MM-DD') as data_roz from sch.idv_p where phone=$1",[req.body.login], function(err, result){
done()
return_data.pupil2 =result
if (err) {
res.end()
return console.error("error")
}
client.query('select * from table1 ($1,$2)',[req.body.login,req.body.date], function(err, result){
return_data.discipline =result 
if (err){
res.end()
return console.error("error")
} 


//3 HERE
client.query("select id from table3 where phone=$1",[req.body.login], function(err, result){
    return_data.id =result 
    if (err){
    res.end()
    return console.error("error")
    }

 res.render('inside',{pupil2:return_data.pupil2,discipline:return_data.discipline,id:return_data.id})
    })})}}


module.exports = {
    post_inside
}
```

server.js

```
app.post('/inside/:id',urlencodedParser,db.post_inside)
```

I want to call the same file, but for example as inside/2124

Comment: Call the request with an `id`. ex: `POST /inside/2124`

Comment: @hoangdv Sorry,I can't understand what do you mean

Comment: Show your the request, where you got back the error `Error: Cannot POST /inside`

Answer (score 0):

try to remove **urlencodedParser** from app.post from 2nd parameter and keep db.post_inside as 2nd parameter.

instead of that try to use

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // true or false
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: try with static simple one, like **app.post('/inside/:id',urlencodedParser,(req,res) => {res.send('success response')})**, if its working fine, then your routes.js code has some problem. debug it.